# Showing a statistic is not complete

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Show that the order statistics from an i.i.d sample from the family of
>   all symmetric distributions on the line with known center of symmetry
>   are not complete.

So without loss of generality, I can assume that the center of symmetry is along the origin by just reshifting the distribution. So let $f_\theta(x)$ be a distribution with symmetry along $x=0$.

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be an i.i.d sample from $f_\theta$ and $X_{(1)}, \cdots, X_{(n)}$ be the order statistics

I need to show that there exists some nonzero $\delta(X_{(1)}, \cdots, X_{(n)})$ so that $E_\theta\left[\delta(X_{(1)}, \cdots, X_{(n)}) \right] = 0$

But I'm unsure how to proceed. I would imagine that when integrating $\delta$ over a symmetric distribution, I should be able to exploit the symmetry to have $\delta \neq 0$ but the integral will be.

Comment: What is your definition of a complete statistic?

Comment: @NigelOvermars Our definition is that a statistics $T(X)$ is complete if for all $\theta$, $E_\theta [\delta(T)] = 0$ implies $\delta(T) = 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about, for odd $n$,  $\delta(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})=\varphi(X_{((n+1)/2)})$, where $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, bounded and anti-symmetric. ($X_{((n+1)/2)}$, the sample median, has a distribution symmetric about $0$, because the distirbution of the order statistics is anti-invariant under reflection about $0$.) Something similar will work for even $n$.

Comment: Hi John. Would you mind adding a little explanation for why that works for $n$ odd? It's not clear to me why that should work

Comment: I've added some further explanation to my answer.